# Rails - Active Record Join across 3 Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

somewhat new to Rails, so I'd appreciate any help you guys could offer.

Anyway, I have three models - Vote, Lunch, and Provider, and I'm looking to write a single Active Record call to pull:

- All the data in the Vote table
- The Lunch date in the Lunch table
- The Provider name in the Provider table

The Vote model includes a lunch_id, the Lunch model includes a lunch_id (just called id) and the provider_id.  The Provider model has a provider_id (just called an id.)  In the Rails console, I can write:

```
v = Vote.joins(:lunch).select("lunches.date,votes.*").where(lunch_id: 1)
```

and that outputs all the data in the Vote model, plus the associated date from the Lunch model.  Where I'm stuck is that I don't know how to "nest" this to then join to the Provider model.

I'm thinking this may have something to do with "has_many_through", but even after reading the documentation, I'm not sure how it would be implemented.  Any thoughts here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming all of your models have the correct `has_many` and `belongs_to` associations defined, you can join in multiple tables by passing in a hash to the join method instead of just a symbol.

```
Vote.joins(lunch: :provider).select('lunches.date, providers.name, votes.*').where(lunch_id: 1)
```

More information about these can be found in the 'Using Array/Hash of Named Associations' portion of the rails query inferface documentation.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations

Comment: That worked like a charm.  What would the syntax be if you had a fourth table, would a hash still work, since you now have potentially three ids to join on, and not just two? 
also, in the hash,  :provider is a symbol, but what is the "lunch:" referred to as? It always trips me up in Rails, switching the colon back and forth.

Comment: Using something like `lunch: :provider` is shortcut syntax for `{ :lunch => :provider }`, it simply means that `:lunch` is a key with a value of `:provider`, while also being a symbol itself.  If you were to join even more tables, you could do so by providing nested hashes, such as `joins(table1: { table2: { table3: :table4 } })`.  I've updated the answer with the link to the rails documentation which contains additional examples for these techniques.